# Scheduling time interval : Protractor

Tags: automated-testing, protractor

I have written some E2E testcases using protractor, selenium-server and angularjs, now I want to run the same testcases(with or without any change) again and again by setting some time interval for running, is there any way to do this,

I have seen jasmine and grunt, but I think they will work if found any change in file, but I have required to run all testcases after some interval(still if there is no change in file)

Comment: Not sure about this, but have you explored Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

If your Protractor scripts are set up to where they can be run VIA command line easily, you can set up a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)-like system to have them run in a predefined schedule.

For Windows based system [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron) should give the information needed.

For Linux based systems [this guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) has a good tutorial for it.

And for Mac systems, [here is a guide](http://www.techradar.com/us/how-to/computing/apple/terminal-101-creating-cron-jobs-1305651).